# Please help me get the java command to work

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm learning how to make and run Java programs in Windows with Notepad and the command line.  Right now I'm getting a well-known error when I try to run any sort of variant of java Main, Main being the starting class of the program, and I've done some research on it.  The error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, but any of the normal solutions for this error don't seem to be helping.

The program is in `<root>\com\zork`, and the classes are Main, Dungeon, and DungeonMaster, each in the package com.zork.  They've all compiled just fine with the javac command, but attempting to run the program with java Main in either `<root>\com\zork` or just `<root>` keeps giving me the error above.  I've tried many things with -cp, -classpath, and where I'm running java from.  The current classpath is 
`<this directory doesn't matter>;.;"C:\Users\intprof\Desktop\ZORK in Java"`,
although the last entry has also been `C:\Users\intprof\Desktop\ZORK in Java\com\zork`, nonexistent, and a couple of other things.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I did Google it. I saw many statements about how to get it to work, none of which worked for me. I said above that I had done some reasearch on this.

Comment: Let me ask you something, Adam. When someone Googles something for about 15 minutes, sifting through one page on the subject after another, each of which containing a legitimate solution on the problem, and yet not a single one of those solutions works - at that point, what good has Googling it done them? They need to turn to forums to seek aid on the particular situation.  That is what forums are for.  This is sort of the same thing that has been portrayed in the Bing commercials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `java com.zork.Main`.

Comment: Thanks, man.  I tried slashes, like with javac, but I didn't try this out.